# Slow join in pyspark, tried repartition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to left join 2 tables on Spark 3, with 17M rows (events)  and 400M rows (details).
have an EMR cluster of 1 + 15 x 64core instances. (r6g.16xlarge tried with similar r5a)
Source files are unpartitioned parquet loaded from S3.

this is the code I'm using to join:

```
join = (
    broadcast(events).join(
        details,
        [
            details["a"] == events["a2"],
            (unix_timestamp(events["date"]) - unix_timestamp(details["date"])) / 3600
            > 5,
        ],
        "left",
    )
).drop("a")

join.checkpoint()
```

To partition I'm using this:

```
executors = 15 * 64 * 3  # 15 instances, 64 cores, 3 workers per core
```

so I tried:

```
details = details.repartition(executors, "a")
```

and

```
details = details.withColumn("salt", (rand(seed=42) * nSaltBins).cast("int"))
details = details.repartition(executors, "salt")
```

In both scenarios, 90% of the workers end in around 5-10 minutes and the rest continue for a LONG time (50+minutes), long green line, no memory or disk errors on the log.

There is a little skewness after partitioning (all partitions between 180k and 160k rows), nothing accountable for more than 50 minutes of processor time.

Any idea of what I could be overseeing? Read a ton of posts and still feel that the green lines (worker time) should be closer between each other, they are all starting at the same time, they are not waiting for a worker to end.

Thanks!

--Edit---
Removed broadcast

On job 11, stage 17 it does 974/1000 in 2 minutes and 30 min later still on 993/1000, previous step uses the salted partitions (given by the executors variable) and it's very fast.

Execution plan:

```
Using 17906254 events
== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan (13)
+- Project (12)
   +- SortMergeJoin LeftOuter (11)
      :- Sort (4)
      :  +- Exchange (3)
      :     +- Project (2)
      :        +- Scan parquet  (1)
      +- Sort (10)
         +- Exchange (9)
            +- Exchange (8)
               +- Project (7)
                  +- Filter (6)
                     +- Scan parquet  (5)
```

[image: as image]

An example of 2h and more of 25% of that time is 1 executor remaining
[image]

Current spark configuration:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Test').config("spark.driver.memory", "108g").config(
        "spark.executor.instances", "59").config("spark.executor.memoryOverhead", "13312").config(
        "spark.executor.memory", "108g").config("spark.executor.cores", "15").config("spark.driver.cores", "15").config(
        "spark.default.parallelism", "1770").config("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", "true").config(
        "spark.sql.adaptive.skewJoin.enabled", "true").config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "885").getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Also try to repartition events as well as it could be a Sort Merge Join.

Comment: you should drop the broadcast

Comment: Added execution plan to post, removed broadcast @AdibP Thanks!

Comment: @hagarwal just to understand, why will this help? added execution plan, thanks!

Comment: @hagarwal it appears to work a little better with this, but then gets stuck too, I did the partition by salting and another by the field of the join (very skewed) Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your issue looks like a nice case of skewed join where some partition will get a lot more data than the others and thus slow the complete job.

Repartitioning your dataframe before your join will not help because the SortMergeJoin operation will repartition again on your join keys to process the join

Since you're using Spark 3, you should have support for the [automatic skewJoin management](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html#optimizing-skew-join).

To use it, make sure you have both `spark.sql.adaptive.enabled=true` (it's false by default in standard Spark distribution) and `spark.sql.adaptive.skewJoin.enabled=true`

If you can't use automatic skewJoin optimization, you can fix it manually with something like this:

- duplicate N times your small dataset

```py
n = 10   # Chose an appropriate amount based on skewness
skewedEvents = events.crossJoin(spark.range(0,n).withColumnRenamed("id","eventSalt"))
```

- seed your large dataset with a random column value between 0 and N

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

skewedDetails = details.withColumn("detailSalt", (f.rand() * n).cast("int"))
```

- join using your salt in the join key and then drop the salt

```py
joined = skewedEvents.join(skewedDetails,[         [
            skewedDetails["a"] == skewedEvents["a2"],
            skewedDetails["detailSalt"] == skewedEvents["eventSalt"],
            (unix_timestamp(skewedEvents["date"]) - unix_timestamp(skewedDetails["date"])) / 3600
            > 5,
        ],
        "left")\
        .filter("a is not null or (a is null and eventSalt = 0)")\
        .drop("a").drop("eventSalt").drop("detailSalt")
```

Note that also may want to validate your query join condition because the UI shows that with 333 million rows processed on details and 17 million on events you generated more than 5 billions output rows, so you may match more rows that you think with your join condition.

Comment: Added current spark configuration updated with your input

Comment: Update! it ends now, that's great, the CustomShuffleReader is only doing "coalesced" so setting the partitons to spark.sql.shuffle.partitions. The output of the SortMergeJoin showed 27 billion rows, and it increased to 44 with the last 3 executors (numbers are changing because I made a mistake in a comparison on the join, fixed now), should I try to salt it? don't want to mess with the AQE. Thanks!!!

Comment: with AQE, you typically want to set `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` or `spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.initialPartitionNum` to a high value for your data volume, and let AQE coalesce the too small partitions. You can the number of rows of the biggest tasks to see if the skew is still significant enough to warrant manual salting. You may also want to adjust your executors to 5 cores/ 31G heap memory, you'll probably get some additional performance boost

Comment: Thanks! testing that because the posted approach have OOM errors, removed the checkpoint too, now AQE is using 3500 partitions of 9MB...I'll tell you how this goes, thanks!

Comment: Related question, because at the time of posting didn't know the problem could be in any other place, sort of complete code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68968011/join-computed-twice-on-pyspark-maybe-i-dont-understand-lazyness

Comment: Wouldn't duplicating `skewedEvents` N times and doing an **outer** join  as suggested produce N-1 extra rows for each event? With inner join it wouldnt be a problem, but in this case you'd need some sort of "clean-up" afterwards.

Comment: you're right. since it's an outer it needs a filter before dropping the salts. I've updated the answer

Comment: Thanks, I let it run through the night, apparently, I have a "No space left on device error", no previous spill errors, no checkpoint this time so doesn't have to force a write. This is turning me crazy. thinking in giving more disk space. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, trying to deskew by code: withColumnRenamed("id","eventSalt")  <<there, what column do you refer to by ID? my "a2"? trying to understand what's happening on that line. thanks!

Comment: spark.range() creates a data frame with a single column `id` so I renamed it as eventSalt to make the intent explicit.

Comment: Great results with this, from error at 6hs to completed in less than 40 minutes! I still don't understand how the salt works on the join, why it doesn't filter data? I'll make this resolved, I'll like to understand that last thing. Thanks!

Comment: On the large dataframe, the salt is used to randomly split the keys in N splits (thus reducing the larger partition size by a factor N). To use these splits, you need to join on (key + salt) thus you also need a salt on the small table side. Since all splits may possibly join on any row in the small table, salt can't be assigned randomly so we assign it by copying all the rows for each salt value. The final filter is required because you're doing a left outer join on your small dataset and if no key is found in the large dataset, you will have your output rows duplicated N times.

Comment: any suggestion if both tables are big? @rluta

Answer (score -1):

broadcast() is used to cache data on each executor (instead of sending the data with every task) but it's not working too well with very large amounts of data. It seems here that 17M rows was a bit too much.

Pre-partitionning your source data before the join could also help if the partitioning of the source data is not optimized for the join. You'll want partition around the column you use for the join. Usually data should be partitionned depending on how it's consumed.

Comment: Hi! as stated in previous comments no big improvement removing broadcast, and the result partitions get VERY skewed if partitioned by the id used on the join :(