# Join computed twice on pyspark, maybe I dont understand lazyness?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

too long since I used spark last time, I'm on it again with Spark 3.1, and here is my issue:
I have 20M rows left joined 400M rows, the original code is:

```
times= [50000,20000,10000,1000]
for time in times:
    join = (df_a.join(df_b,
                                 [
                                     df_a["a"] == df_b["a"],
                                     (unix_timestamp(events["date"]) - unix_timestamp(details["date"])) / 3600
                                     > 5,
                                     (df_a["task"]) = (df_b["task"]-time))
                                 ], 'left')
```

knowing that each iteration (time variable) contains the next I thought in making the DataFrame lighter before comparing with each value, so coded this:

```
times= [50000,20000,10000,1000]

join = (df_a.join(df_b,
                                 [
                                     df_a["a"] == df_b["a"],
                                     (unix_timestamp(events["date"]) - unix_timestamp(details["date"])) / 3600
                                     > 5,
                                     (df_a["task"]) = (df_b["task"]-50000))
                                 ], 'left')

join.checkpoint() # Save current state, and cleaned dataframe

for time in times:
    step_join = join_df.where((join_df["task"]) = (join_df["task"]-time)))
    # Make calculations and Store result for the iteration...
```

When looking at the visual SQL diagram on the Spark history server, it seems that my improved solution (?) on the second join is not used, it makes the whole left join again on each iteration, not making use of the cleaner, lighter DataFrame.

My final idea was to use the new df for the next iteration so each filter will be lighter.  Are my thoughts correct? am I missing something?

Image of how it looks like, this is a still-running code, the SortMergeJoin of the middle is the decoupled to filter, the second "Filter" only filters a little more, but on left and right you can see that it's computing again the SortMergeJoin instead of reusing the previously calculated.
[image]

And this is how the processing looks like, same calculations each time plus filter
[image]

Last time have to remove the checkpoint because with 55B rows on a join it was hard to store the data (>100TB)

My cluster configuration for 30 instances 64vcore 488GB RAM + driver

```
        "spark.executor.instances", "249").config("spark.executor.memoryOverhead", "10240").config(
        "spark.executor.memory", "87g").config("spark.executor.cores", "12").config("spark.driver.cores", "12").config(
        "spark.default.parallelism", "5976").config("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", "true").config(
        "spark.sql.adaptive.skewJoin.enabled", "true").config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "3100").config(
        "spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead", "10240").config("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", "2100").config(
        "spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY").getOrCreate()
```

I'm using the excel calculator on this site for tunning of everything except **spark.sql.shuffle.partitions** https://www.c2fo.io/c2fo/spark/aws/emr/2016/07/06/apache-spark-config-cheatsheet/ now using 10 executors per node

Tried using .cache() on the join it's still slower than the 4 paralel joins, the first join es muy slower.
Note that .cache() is good for a subset but for a 100TB join result it would be slower because it will cache to disk.
thanks!

Comment: It's quite hard to make sense of what you're trying to do from the question but I would guess that looping 4 joins on the same datasets is probably not the correct solution. Maybe you explain more the problem you're trying to solve, is it an attribution model ?

Comment: I'm making multiple groups bound to time and then making multiple aggregations, these groups are filtered using the time in task "a" and task "b", that's why I need to join it, then for each group I made some calculations like sum/avg/etc and create a  dataframe with all the aggregations for each time window

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer(5/9/2021):**

I think you can try to specify a partition column in your data with `withColumn` method by specifying values in `when(.. ,.. ).otherwise(..)` after the join (you can nest multiple when/otherwise blocks for 4 different values). Than just write your data with `partitionBy`. In this case you won't need to recalculate 4 times. One calculation will be enough.

**Old Answer:**

I think you may want to use `df.cache()` function to prevent same calculations.

```py
join_df = (df_a.join(df_b,
                                 [
                                     df_a["a"] == df_b["a"],
                                     (unix_timestamp(events["date"]) - unix_timestamp(details["date"])) / 3600
                                     > 5,
                                     (df_a["task"]) = (df_b["task"]-50000))
                                 ], 'left').cache()
```

Spark will calculate and persist all results into memory & disk. It will reuse pre-calculated `join_df` for new filters.

Comment: I don't think I have 100+TB for the caching, maybe I can add some disk (cheaper than ram on AWS). Isn't a lot for caching? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, disk would be much cheaper, but memory is much more faster. Unfortunately in spark, to prevent calculations we need to cache it otherwise it will try to recalculate on each action. If one of your table is small you can also try to broadcast it like `df_a.join(broadcast(df_b), ...` which will prevent shuffles.

Comment: Gb of data on both sides, broadcast slows the job, got to look if the time to save on disk is less than make that join 4 times

Comment: With memory cache, it was slower than executing the 4 joins...not sure why, the main join took more time than the 4 individual joins in the for loop

Comment: Updated to las config used +  results with cache (not suitable for a larger dataset)

Comment: Hmm, in this case your total amout of base reading data is much lower than joined value, because of that caching is slower in your case. I think you can try to specify a partition column in your data with `withColumn` mathob by specifying vales in `when(.. ,.. ).otherwise)` after the join. than just write your data with `partitionBy`. In this case you won't need to recalculate 4 times. one calculation will be enough.

Comment: Updated the answer for this.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, crazy week here, I googled a bit and don't quite understand how to apply your solution on my code, the result of each join is a dataframe for a specific time delay and then I do some operations with each time window. How would ```when otherwise``` enter in play here? thanks!